# Silent Installation of SQl Express 2005

Tags: installation, sql-server-express, silent

Can anyone please let me know the procedure to perform silent installation of SQL Server Express 2005 and the way to specify the installation parameters.

Answer (score 7):

Get the MSI and do

```
string InstallFile = "SSCERuntime-ENU-x86.msi"
string LogFile = "C:\Install.log"

Process proc;
proc = Process.Start("msiexec", "/l " + LogFile + " /quiet /i " + InstallFile);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this to support deployment of a desktop application, it's a bad idea.

Use the Compact Edition of SQL Server rather than Express Edition.  It's more suited to in-process situations, and it's much easier to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for a prompt reply , I would try it ,
but i am loooking something like this for SQL EXPRESS
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can find the variables here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154(SQL.90).aspx

You should be able to install silently using msiexec  /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress ADDLOCAL=ALL INSTANCENAME=  SAPWD=

You may want to set some other vars that you can find in the above link lik SQLAUTOSTART and DISABLENETWORKPROTOCOLS.